# Node.js redirect after use request to POST information

Tags: node.js, post, request, graphql

currently I am using Express, Node.js, Graphql to build backend server,
I want to POST data into an online payment system, when I successfully used request to post data, I found that it can console an HTML body in my terminal, but what I want is the Graphql interface can redirect to the platform rather than just output the HTML body, what can I do to solve this problem? Here is my code for the reference.

```
Mutation: {
    createPayment: async (parent, args, { models, user }) => {
      const MerchantID = Merchantvalue;
      const TotalAmt = await args.TotalAmt;
      const ItemName = await args.ItemName;
      const ChoosePayment = await args.ChoosePayment;
      const PaymentType = payment value;
      const TradeDesc = await args.TradeDesc;
      const ReturnURL = returnurl;
      const EncryptType = encry;
      const MerchantTradeNo = await CheckMacValue.random;
      const MerchantTradeDate = await CheckMacValue.datetime;
      const TheCheckMacValue = await CheckMacValue.PaymentOnceValue(
        MerchantID, PaymentType, TotalAmt, TradeDesc,
        ItemName, ReturnURL, ChoosePayment, EncryptType,
      );

      const formData = {
        MerchantID: MerchantID,
        MerchantTradeNo: MerchantTradeNo,
        MerchantTradeDate: MerchantTradeDate,
        TotalAmount: TotalAmt,
        ItemName: ItemName,
        ChoosePayment: ChoosePayment,
        PaymentType: PaymentType,
        TradeDesc: TradeDesc,
        ReturnURL: ReturnURL,
        EncryptType: EncryptType,
        CheckMacValue: TheCheckMacValue,
      };
//In here I can successfully post data, but I want to redirect rather than just console the body in terminal.

      request.post(
        { url: 'https://payment-stage.ecpay.com.tw/Cashier/AioCheckOut/V5', formData: formData },
        function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log(body);
 });
    },
  },
```

Comment: Have you checked the express documentation? Redirection is pretty easily handled from the response object (see res.redirect([status,] path)): https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: My problem is not res.redirect in RESTful,  What I want is input data into GraphQL and then redirect from GraphQL interface to another website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is to pass the right response (code, message) to the client and handle that redirect logic on the client side (web, mobile, etc.)

Comment: So I need to finish the process in Client SIDE RIGHT?

Comment: not necessary, you can finish the process in the backend side and depending on the response from your post request